# What's the difference between $@ and $1 when there is only one parameter?

Tags: makefile

There are some C code:

**apple.c**

```
 #include<stdio.h>  
 int main(void)  
 {
   printf("apple\n");
   return 0;
 }
```

**Makefile**

```
apple:  
     gcc -c $@.c  
     gcc  $@.o -o $@
```

`$ make apple`
and it works perfectly. But if I modify `Makefile` as:

```
apple:
     gcc -c $1.c
     gcc $1.o -o $1
```

`$ make apple`
It does not work. What is the difference between `$@` and `$1` when there is only one parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a shell script, there'd be no difference. But this is a Makefile, so these references are to [make variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html#Using-Variables). `$@` is the [name of the rule target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) (`apple` here), while `$1` is a variable named `1`—nothing special. Bash does not see these variable references; they're handled by make.

```
$ cat Makefile 
1 = one

target:
    @echo '@ = $@'
    @echo '1 = $1'

$ make
@ = target
1 = one
```